# ajuda para nao repetir o mesmo case de um switch dentro de um for (c#)

Tags: c#

Estou no primeiro periodo de um curso de SI e preciso fazer um jogo de truco e me deparei como uma situacao que nao estou conseguindo solucionar. Preciso que durando o loop eu nao possa repetir o mesmo case nas jogadas do truco.
Segue o metodo:

```
static void jogo()
{

    for (int jogada = 0; jogada<3; jogada++)
    {            
        if(jogador1jogada == 2 || jogador2jogada == 2)
        {
            break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Qual carta vc ira jogar? ");
        escolha = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (escolha)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("Voce jogou a carta: " + jogador1[0]);
                IAjogo();
                Console.WriteLine("A IA jogou: " + jogador2[escolhaIA - 1]);
                verificavitoria();                                              
            break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("Voce jogou a carta: " + jogador1[1]);
                IAjogo();
                Console.WriteLine("A IA jogou: " + jogador2[escolhaIA - 1]);
                verificavitoria();                    
            break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("Voce jogou a carta: " + jogador1[2]);
                IAjogo();
                Console.WriteLine("A IA jogou: " + jogador2[escolhaIA - 1]);
                verificavitoria();                    
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: A pergunta está confusa. Por que `durante o loop não pode repetir o mesmo case na jogadas`? O que dizer com isto? Qual é o seu problema? Que solução precisa?

Comment: pq no truco a sua mao tem 3 cartas, quando voce joga uma voce nao pode jogar a mesma carta denovo

Comment: Eu até entendo isso, mas sua pergunta não reflete isso e pelo que entendi as respostas também não entenderam isso e falaram de uma outra coisa completamente diferente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perceba que a única coisa que muda em cada um dos cases é o valor de `X` em `Console.WriteLine("Voce jogou a carta: " + jogador1[X])`. Portanto, basta usar apenas uma vez este trecho de código colocando `escolha - 1` no lugar de `X`.

Com isto o case foi eliminado. Posteriormente, você pode preencher a posição do vetor cuja carta foi baixada com "-1" e verificar isto antes de realizar o descarte.

```
for (int jogada = 0; jogada<3; jogada++)
{            
    if(jogador1jogada == 2 || jogador2jogada == 2)
    {
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Qual carta vc ira jogar? ");
    escolha = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    //  evita a reutilização da carta
    if (jogador1[escolha - 1] == "-1") 
    {
        jogada--;
        continue;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Voce jogou a carta: " + jogador1[escolha -1]);
    jogador1[escolha - 1] = "-1" // marca a carta como já utilizada
    IAjogo();
    Console.WriteLine("A IA jogou: " + jogador2[escolhaIA - 1]);
    verificavitoria();                                              
}
```

Comment: tentei subsituir aqui mas nao esta funcionando pois esta dando erro alegando que nao e possivel converter tipo int em string nem comprar string e int

Comment: Ah, jogador1[ ] armazena strings. Grave alguma string, exemplo "-1" ou "utilizada", sinalizando a utilização da carta nos dois locais em que anteriormente sugeri o uso de -1 (exemplo jogador1[escolha - 1] == "-1" e jogador1[escolha - 1] = "-1"). Alterei lá na resposta.

Comment: agr rodou mas só esta rodando uma vez, na hora de tacar a segunda carta ele fecha

Comment: Ah sim, tem outro problema, quando o descarte de uma carta falha, temos de reincrementar a variável jogada (jogada++ antes do continue). O break no final eu tinha de ter removido, corrigi na resposta também. Devido ao break que esqueci no final ele tava saindo do Loop.

Comment: realmente agr nao esta dando pra tacar a mesma carta, muito obrigado, porem o programa esta fechando se eu tento tacar a msm, coloquei dentro do if um writeline pra ele escolher outra carta porem o programa nao continua do msm jeito, e IA continua tacando a msm carta, mas aí acho q tenho q alterar no metodo da IA q ainda nao mexi ne?

Comment: Cara, fiz tudo errado, onde botei jogada++ é jogada--. Foi mal.

Comment: agora deu certin vlwwws!!!

Comment: Quanto ao IAjogo eu imaginei que você teria algum problema. Eu pensaria em criar uma classe base Jogador e duas subclasses JogadorIA e JogadorHumano. O loop que realiza as várias mãos do jogo ficaria fora destas classes, em uma outra classe Jogo por exemplo.

Comment: Pense em termos de entidades. Quem sabe como quer jogar é um jogador, mas quem controla a dinâmica do jogo é uma série de regras que são independentes de quem for o jogador. Se achar que ajudei, valida a resposta aí. Valeus.

Comment: entendi, eu ainda nao sei como usar classes mas vc ajudou bastante vou ver o que posso fazer aqui. Como eu valido a resposta?? nao sei fazer isso, primeira vez por aqui

Comment: Também não sei, sou novo por aqui, nunca fiz uma pergunta. De alguma forma tem como aceitar a resposta como válida. Ela passa a aparecer com um V verde do lado dela.

Comment: Acho que foi vlwws!!

Answer (score 0):

Crie um array de string, e adicione valor se a opção foi escolhida, antes do switch faça um if para verificar se a opção já foi escolhida, se já foi, entra no else dando mensagem de erro e colocando o valor de jogada -1 para não incrementar a jogada e ficar repetindo até o valor seja válido.

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {

    var test = new string[3];
    Console.WriteLine("Atribuir o valor quando o valor for escolhido dentro do case");
    Console.WriteLine(test[0] = "1");
    Console.WriteLine(test[1] = "2");
    Console.WriteLine(test[2]);

    Console.WriteLine("Ver se é nulo, se for, não há valores");
    Console.WriteLine(test[0] == null);
    Console.WriteLine(test[1] == null);
    Console.WriteLine(test[2] == null);
  }
}
```

No exemplo acima coloquei a string 1 e 2 mas não coloquei 3, o que significa que o jogador já escolheu 1 e 2, falta o 3

```
Atribuir o valor quando o valor for escolhido dentro do case
1
2

Ver se é nulo, se for, não há valores
False
False
True
```

Aí para ver se já escolheu a opção é só checar se é nulo, se for, ainda não foi escolhido, ao final do for é só colocar tudo null novamente.

EDIT: O switch deve ficar dentro do IF, o else depois do switch.

Comment: nao entendi como devo usar isso :(